# CreateProcess works differently on x64 and x86 platform

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess

I am trying to install a driver using inf file through c++ program. The below program works fine in x64 platform and where as fails in x86 platform with GetLastError 2.
What could be the difference here? The reason why I am trying this is, I am using one of the existing application created by my team which is 32 bit application.

```
void StartProcess(LPCTSTR pszTarget, LPCTSTR pszCommandLine, LPCTSTR pszFolder)
{
    try
    {
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        STARTUPINFO si;
        TCHAR szCommandLine[1024];
        
        SecureZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
        SecureZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
        si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
        si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    
        _tcscpy_s(szCommandLine, 1024, pszTarget);
        _tcscat_s(szCommandLine, 1024, _T(" "));
        _tcscat_s(szCommandLine, 1024, pszCommandLine);     

        auto bRetval = CreateProcess(NULL, szCommandLine, 0, 0, FALSE, 0, 0, pszFolder, &si, &pi);

        if (bRetval)
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Installing driver failed. Error details - " + std::to_string(GetLastError()));
        }

        if (pi.hProcess)
        {
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        }

        if (pi.hThread)
        {
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        throw e;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string sWorkingFolder = "<inf folder path>";
    std::string sBin = "pnputil.exe";
    std::string sParams = "/add-driver \"<infpath>\" /install";
    StartProcess(sBin.c_str(), sParams.c_str(), sWorkingFolder.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error code 2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Are you certain the paths you're using are correct for 32-bit? Registry and filesystem virtualization may be a problem.

Comment: Is `TCHAR` the same type in both compilations?

Comment: @RetiredNinja How to ensure the correct path 32-bit? Same code built using x64 platform works fine.